# using CAST to remove time from getdate to get results from last 7 days FROM yesterday

Tags: sql-server

i am using this statement

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT CONVERT(varchar(255), [Reg Date1], 103) AS [Reg Date], Regs
FROM         (SELECT     CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(255), SetupDateTime, 101)) AS [Reg Date1], COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS Regs
                       FROM          dbo.tbl_User
WHERE SetupDateTime
BETWEEN (DATEADD (dd , -7 , GETDATE())) AND (DATEADD (dd , -1 , GETDATE()))
GROUP BY CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(255), SetupDateTime, 101))) AS tb
ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, [Reg Date1])
```

which works perfectl;y and gets the last 7 days from yesterday.

However it gets the results from this time yesterday but i want it to get all of the results from yesterday so i know im to use a cast .....

CAST(FLOOR( CAST( GETDATE() AS FLOAT ) )AS DATETIME)

but i cant seem to get it to work alongside this query.

any help?

Answer (score 1):

wow! what version of microsoft sql server are you using?
try this

```
select @@VERSION
```

results for me:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64)   Sep 21 2011 22:45:45   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

if you don't have DATE datatype, you need to find another way to trunc time from date like this:

```
select convert(char(8), getdate(),112)
```

should return 8 digits YYYYMMDD

```
20111216
```

if you have this result, then you have the solution

Answer (score 0):

to trunc time from datetime use cast(getdate() as date) :

```
select CONVERT(char(10), [Reg Date1], 103) [Reg Date], Regs
from (
      select cast(SetupDateTime as DATE) [Reg Date1], COUNT(distinct ID) [Regs]
      from SetupDateTime
      where cast(SetupDateTime as DATE) 
            between cast((DATEADD (dd , -7 , GETDATE())) AS DATE) 
                and cast((DATEADD (dd , -1 , GETDATE())) AS DATE)
      group by cast(SetupDateTime as DATE)
    ) a
order by a.[Reg Date1]
```

Comment: that didnt work, i changed the from to the table name but it threw loadsa of errors

Comment: getting this error Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type DATE is not a defined system type.